# How to style (this) input element with javascript when in focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of the input element that is in focus.
I've tried with this but it doesn't seem to be working.

#### HTML

```
<li>
   <input id="text1" onfocusout="removeColor()"onfocus="changeColor()" class="slut" value="{{Number}}">
</li>
<li>
    <input id="text1" onfocusout="removeColor()"onfocus="changeColor()" class="slut" value="{{Priority}}">
</li>
```

#### JS

```js
function changeColor() {
    $(this).style.backgroundColor = "red";
};
function removeColor() {
    $(this).style.backgroundColor = "white";
};
```

Comment: It can be done with css only. No need to use javascript. Target class slut or input when its on focus .like input:focus{ background:red}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need CSS for this:

```
input:focus { 
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

I'm sure it was just a quick example, but be aware you have two matching ID's in your code. I guess in fact you might want to go with classes

```
input.yellow:focus { background-color: yellow; }
input.pink:focus { background-color: pink; }
```

For example

Comment: No problem at all, sometimes it's easy to think things are harder than they are ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
input:hover{
  background-color:#ff00ff;
}
```

[js Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ifinto/o2gxgz9r/)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; You can do this without jQuery

**CSS selector**

```
input {
  background-color: white;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**if with jQuery**

```
$('input').focus(function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
$('input').focusout(function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'white');
});
```

**JQUERY: SNIPPET**

```js
$('input').focus(function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
});

$('input').focusout(function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'white');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with jQuery, you could use the `css()` method:

```
function changeColor() {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
}
function removeColor() {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"white"});
}
```

A better way would to do this would be to use a combination of CSS / jQuery:

CSS:

```
.colored {
    background-color: red;
}
:not(.colored) {
    background-color: white;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var colorClass = "colored";
function changeColor() {
    $(this).addClass(colorClass);
}
function removeColor() {
    $(this).removeClass(colorClass);
}
```

I prefer have a single class as a toggle. The advantage of this is you can update and change the styling as much as you want in the CSS without having to change your JavaScript. This is a good separation of concerns. In addition, you could style child elements and have them inherit the toggled state.

Answer (score 0):

first pass `this` in `onfocus`. then change `$(this).style.backgroundColor = "red";` to `$(temp).css("backgroundColor", "red");`

also use `onblur' not`onfocusout`

```js
function changeColor(temp) {
    $(temp).css("backgroundColor", "red");
};
function removeColor(temp) {
    $(temp).css("backgroundColor", "white");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><input id="text1" onblur="removeColor(this)" onfocus="changeColor(this)" class="slut" value=""></li>
<li><input id="text" onblur="removeColor(this)" onfocus="changeColor(this)" class="slut" value=""></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this help